# How to add angular translate to angular material tab?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am currently working on a website which supports two languages. Angular translate is working fine for my whole website, but i can not figure out a way to apply it for md-tab .

```
<md-tab label="Shops Near by">
```

In my translateProvider.translations() i have a variable SHOPS_NEAR_BY with its translation to both the languages. In normal conditions i can use something like :

```
<span translate="SHOPS_NEAR_BY ">
```

and translate will change the value when required.

Can someone help me out with how to apply the same for md-tab ?

Comment: Use the translate filter: `label="{{ 'SHOPS_NEAR_BY' | translate }}"`. https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter

Comment: It does not works, I have tried the same earlier.

Comment: md-tab straight away shows SHOPS NEAR BY as output.

Comment: That probably means the translation are not ready (i.e. loaded) yet when displaying the tabs. Only show them once the translations are ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<md-tab label="{{'SHOPS_NEAR_BY' | translate}}">
```

If it still not showing translation then you must be asynchronously loading those. So for that after resolve of `$translate.use(/lang)` call `$translate()`. To avoid flashing of translations keys & values you can use `translate-cloak` directive.

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nmw7IZ1IZZqB0cSRvMQk?p=preview)

[translate-cloak detail Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6PlzCcFjjtwGyNqSjy43?p=preview)

Check this [github discussion](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1344) about similar issue